# Raylib crashes when creating an array on the heap

Tags: c++, arrays, heap-memory, raylib

I'm quite new to C++, so as an excercise I've been trying to code a game using Raylib and C++, but I ran into an issue. I wanted to make minesweeper and for that I needed a grid which I wanted to represent with two bool arrays and because I wanted the player to input the size of the map I had to initialize the array on the heap.

game.h

```
#pragma once

#include <raylib.h>

class Game
{
    bool* map;
    bool* overlay;
    int width, height;

public:
    Game();
    Game(int _width, int _height, int mines, int seed, int startX, int startY);
    ~Game();
    void tick();
    void draw() const;
};
```

Game.cpp

```
Game::Game(int _width, int _height, int mines, int seed, int startX, int startY) 
{
    map = new bool[width*height];
    overlay = new bool[width*height];
    width = _width;
    height = _height;
    for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++)
        map[i] = false;
    for(int i = 0; i < width*height; i++)
        overlay[i] = true;
    SetRandomSeed(seed);
    for(int i = 0; i < mines; i++)
    {
        int x = GetRandomValue(1, width), y = GetRandomValue(1, height);
        while(map[(x+width*y)-1] || (x == startX && y == startY))
            x = GetRandomValue(1, width), y = GetRandomValue(1, height);
        map[(x+width*y)-1] = true;
    }
}

void Game::draw() const
{
    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            if(overlay[width*y+x])
                DrawRectangle(x*10,y*10, 10, 10, (y+x)%2 == 0 ? DARKGRAY : LIGHTGRAY);
        }
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <raylib.h>

#include "game.h"

int main(void)
{
    InitWindow(800, 450, "raylib [core] example - basic window");
    Game game(24, 24, 5, 0, 0, 0);

    while (!WindowShouldClose())
    {
       //some stuff here
       game.draw();
    } // exception thrown here

    CloseWindow();

    return 0;
}
```

Exception screenshot from visual studio:
[image]

I've tested it and it crashes when I leave

```
for (int i = 0; i < width * height; i++)
    map[i] = false;
for(int i = 0; i < width*height; i++)
    overlay[i] = true;
```

this in the Game constructor.

Comment: Recommendation: Familiarize yourself with [the Rule of Three (and friends)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: Why aren't you using `std::vector` instead?

Comment: And please use a [*debugger*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems) to find out exactly where the crash happens. As well as being able to examine the values of all involved variables when it happens.

Comment: Check the order of these four lines: `map = new bool[width*height];`, `overlay = new bool[width*height];`, `width = _width;`, `height = _height;`. What do they tell you about the values of `width` and `height` when they are used the first time? With the correct compiler warning options turned on the compiler can catch this one for you. Quick hack example: https://godbolt.org/z/E9bTMzo69

Answer (score 0):

Okay, thank you user4581301 for your comment. After checking the code I realized I had initialized the arrays before the width and height so the arrays were using uninitialized values for their size. I simply changed the order in which the values were initialized in the constructor from

```
map = new bool[width*height];
overlay = new bool[width*height];
width = _width;
height = _height;
```

to

```
width = _width;
height = _height;
map = new bool[width*height];
overlay = new bool[width*height];
```

and it worked.